# In blueprintjs tabs component, is there any way to display the tabs on the bottom of the tab panel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, blueprintjs

I am using the tabs component of Version 4 of Blueprintjs, and would like to display the tabs on the bottom of the panel as is typically done in a spreadsheet. There is a setting for moving the tabs to the left side, but I don't see a way to put them on the bottom.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add custom styles for `.bp4-tabs` like:

```css
.bp4-tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

[image]